# When trying to run a pyglet window, I get this error: "AttributeError: 'scipy.spatial.transform._rotation.Rotation' object has no attribute 'as_dcm'"

Tags: python, scipy, pyglet, ratcave

This is all my code

```
import pyglet

import ratcave as rc

window = pyglet.window.Window()

pyglet.app.run()
```

When running this, the following shows in terminal

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\CODING\pyopengl\Mudge-David-Homework-8.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ratcave as rc
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import resources
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\resources.py", line 40, in <module>
    default_camera = Camera()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.projection = PerspectiveProjection() if not projection else projection
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\utils\observers.py", line 56, in __setattr__
    super(AutoRegisterObserver, self).__setattr__(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 299, in projection
    self.reset_uniforms()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 302, in reset_uniforms
    self.uniforms['projection_matrix'] = self.projection_matrix.view()
PS C:\Users\David> & C:/Users/David/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps/python3.10.exe c:/CODING/pyopengl/Mudge-David-Homework-8.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\CODING\pyopengl\Mudge-David-Homework-8.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ratcave as rc
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from . import resources
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\resources.py", line 40, in <module>
    default_camera = Camera()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 260, in __init__
    self.projection = PerspectiveProjection() if not projection else projection
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\utils\observers.py", line 56, in __setattr__
    super(AutoRegisterObserver, self).__setattr__(key, value)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 299, in projection
    self.reset_uniforms()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\camera.py", line 302, in reset_uniforms
    self.uniforms['projection_matrix'] = self.projection_matrix.view()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\shader.py", line 139, in uniforms
    self.update()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\utils\observers.py", line 47, in update
    self.on_change()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\physical.py", line 186, in on_change
    Physical.on_change(self)
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\physical.py", line 138, in on_change
    self.model_matrix = np.dot(self.position.to_matrix(), self.rotation.to_matrix())
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\coordinates.py", line 126, in to_matrix
    return self.to_radians().to_matrix()
  File "C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python310\site-packages\ratcave\coordinates.py", line 95, in to_matrix
    mat[:3, :3] = R.from_euler(self.axes[1:],self._array,degrees=False).as_dcm() # scipy as_matrix() not available
AttributeError: 'scipy.spatial.transform._rotation.Rotation' object has no attribute 'as_dcm'
```

With seemingly the error being that final line
AttributeError: 'scipy.spatial.transform._rotation.Rotation' object has no attribute 'as_dcm'

Im trying to follow [this tutorial](https://ratcave.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial1.html)
The code should create a new window, which in turn means Pyglet is working.

From what I have researched, this has been solved through SciPy methods being changed, which I have attempted with no luck. Another thread of this issue resolved it by installing the correct version, which would correct these methods. However I have attempted to install different versions of SciPy and still get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The `as_dcm()` method of the `Rotation` class was [deprecated in SciPy version 1.4.0](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/release.1.4.0.html#scipy-deprecations) and removed from SciPy version 1.6.0.  You'll have to use an older version of SciPy, or find out if there is a version of `ratcave` that works with the latest version of SciPy.